# Filter is collapsing the list view

Tags: android

```
public class ListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    SharedPreferences get;
    Context context;
    private final String [] values;
    private final List<String> numbers;
    private final List<Integer> images;
    SharedPreferences.Editor put ;

    HashMap<String, Boolean> lawde = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    private List<String>originalData = null;
    private List<String>filteredData = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();


    private com.example.suma.ListAdapter2.ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


    public ListAdapter2(Context context, List<String> name, List<String> price, List<Integer> images){
        //super(context, R.layout.single_list_app_item, utilsArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.values =   name.toArray(new String[0]);
        this.numbers = price;
        this.images = images;


        this.originalData = name;
        this.filteredData = name;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++){

            info.put(name.get(i),price.get(i)+":subi"+images.get(i));

        }


        get= context.getSharedPreferences("CART", MODE_PRIVATE);
        put= context.getSharedPreferences("CART", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    }





    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {

        return filteredData.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("filtered data", String.valueOf(filteredData.size()));
        Log.d("current pos", String.valueOf(position));
        com.example.suma.ListAdapter2.ViewHolder viewHolder=null;

        final View result;



        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new com.example.suma.ListAdapter2.ViewHolder();

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item2, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aNametxt);
            viewHolder.txtVersion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aVersiontxt);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIconIV);
         viewHolder.check=convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);







            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (com.example.suma.ListAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        if (lawde.size()>0) {
            if (lawde.containsKey(filteredData.get(position))) {
                Log.d("thvadiya", String.valueOf(lawde));
                viewHolder.check.setChecked(lawde.get(filteredData.get(position)));
            }
        }


        viewHolder.check.
                setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {



Log.d("omalee","agudhu");
                          lawde.put(filteredData.get(position),isChecked);
Log.d("lawdi",String.valueOf(lawde));



                        Log.d("lawda",String.valueOf(lawde));


                    }
                });


        viewHolder.txtName.setText(filteredData.get(position));
        String[] splited=info.get(filteredData.get(position)).split (":subi");
        viewHolder.txtVersion.setText("₹" + splited[0]+"/ KG");

        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(splited[1]));



        Log.d("okali", info.get(filteredData.get(position)));







        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }





    private static class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtVersion;
        ImageView icon;
        TextView status;
        TextView add,minus;
CheckBox check;

    }
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();


            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

            Log.e("haha", String.valueOf(filteredData)+"oops");
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
        public void updatelistview(){

            Log.d("both", String.valueOf(get.getAll()));
        };


    }



}
```

All works fine !, but whenever I try to filter the method in this adapter, it is automatically add values to lawde(hashmap) , I don't know what is happening here, I constructed this code for 10 days but I am still struggling to find out where I went wrong , and I am using filter on on text change method on search view